# App Crashes after first settimeout on svelte using class

Tags: javascript, class, settimeout, svelte

I'm trying to solve this scoping problem (i think) with classes, svelte and setTimeOut function.

The problem is that it is returning an error, after the first loop. But I don't know how to solve it.

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Sample from "./ClassSample"

    let cs = new Sample(0,1);

    cs.zeroToOne();
</script>
```

ClassSample.js

```
var Sample= class Sample {

    constructor (_zero, _one) {
        this.zero = _zero;
        this.one = _one;
    }

    getZero() { return this.zero; }
    getOne() { return this.one; }

    zeroToOne() { 
        console.log(this.getOne());

        setTimeout(this.zeroToOne, 50);

    }
}

export default Sample;
```

Error message:
message: "this.getOne is not a function"

After printing the first "1"

Comment: Never used svelte, but first thing I would try is `setTimeout(this.zeroToOne.bind(this), 50);`

Comment: Or `setTimeout(() => this.zeroToOne(), 50)`

Comment: That worked perfectly @dave. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The error is because function executed by `setTimeout` will have different scope.

You'll need something like this:

```
var Sample= class Sample {

    constructor (_zero, _one) {
        this.zero = _zero;
        this.one = _one;
    }

    getZero() { return this.zero; }
    getOne() { return this.one; }

    zeroToOne() { 
        console.log(this.getOne());
        const that = this;
        setTimeout(function(){that.zeroToOne()}, 50);

    }
}

export default Sample;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe @vanowm is spot-on as far as the solution to your problem goes. I'd just like to add that setTimeout is perfectly reliable in its simplicity. Approaching any bugfest while suspecting setTimeout is arguably the wrong course of action in any real-world scenario.

As in the grand scheme of things, if anything is consistently crashing after it runs, then by far the most likely explanation is that you have a scoping issue with your callbacks. Or whatever resource was next in line in the event loop.